# How to load messages in the last hour only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

In the `json` file there are messages of this kind (in the "time" date in milliseconds)

```js
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
callback([{
  "time": "1499204237",
  "user": "Max",
  "message": "Hello"
}, {
  "time": "1499204238",
  "user": "Mike",
  "message": "Hi"
}]);

function callback(respond) {
  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];
    var now = new Date();
    var time = (data.time);
    for(var j = 0; j < time.length; j++){
        var time_diff = time[j] - now;
    while(time_diff < 3600){
    var date = new Date(+time * 1000);
    var new_date = new Date(date);
    var res = [new_date.getHours(), new_date.getMinutes(), new_date.getSeconds()].map(function (x) {
     return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
    }).join(":");
    var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
    $('#messages').append(rowClone);
    $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
    $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
    $('.message', rowClone).html(data.message);
    $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());
    }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 255px;
  max-height: 255px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table#messages {
  min-height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

tr {
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
}

td.time,
td.name {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="easyForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
```

I need to download all the messages from the file and select the last of them (last hour).
In `for` loop want to select each `"time"` from all messages and count the difference with `"now"`. So i need try to do that, but i thing my `for loop` is not correct.What's wrong?

Comment: The server should only send new messages to the client, it's inefficient from the point of view of network bandwidth to send all messages on every request and let the client filter them out.  Perhaps the client could send the date or id of the last message received and the server replies with new messages.